# Basic functionality impaired if images are disabled

Tags: support, accessibility

Trying to browse Gaming.SE with images disabled is a far more trying experience than either StackOverflow or say UX.SE etc.

Some of the UI features that disappear

- The user info section (username section before the search bar)
- 'Ask a Question' link
- Questions, Tags etc. section links

Could someone look into this and fix the CSS so it is more readable?

[image: Screenshot with images off]

Comment: What is "the main site"? Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Added a screenshot :)

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Well, then stop doing that!"

Answer (score 2):

A proper image-less experience would show you the actual text of the buttons, as you can see by looking at the source of the page. For example the upvote button should show the "up vote" text as the source reveals:

```
<a class="vote-up-off"
   title="This question shows research effort;
          it is useful and clear (click again to undo)">
  up vote
</a>
```

You must be doing something wrong.

Can I interest you in the mobile view perhaps? Click the 'mobile' link at the bottom.

Comment: I'd actually not noticed the mobile view, but it just doesn't display Ask Question etc. at all which is not what I want. Above screenshot is on plain FF with Web Developer extn., Images->Disable Images->All Images